# rpc mechanism to use with select driven daemon

Tags: select, asynchronous, daemon, rpc

I want to add an RPC service to my unix daemon.  The daemon is written in C and has an event driven loop implemented using select().  I've looked at a number of RPC implementations but they all seem to involve calling a library routine, or auto generated code, which blocks indefinitely.

Are there any RPC frameworks out there where the library code/autogenerated code doesn't block or start threads.  Ideally, I'd like to create the input/output sockets myself and pass them into my select loop.

Regards,

Alex - first time poster! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you can use C++ [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) is good - [FAST RPC](http://fastrpc.sourceforge.net/?page=example&sub=example-c) is also useful.

I evaluated a fair few libraries at the start of 2012 and eventually ended up going with [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) as it was more adaptable and (I found it) easier and a lot more flexible. I did consider using a [Google protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations) implementation but ended up using a simpler structured command text approach.

I probably wouldn't consider doing this in C unless I had to, in which case I'd probably start with the standard rpc(3) stuff, for a good overview see this  [overview of Remote Procedure Calls (RPC)](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html).

Comment: It looks like Thrift requires you to call server.serve(), and rpc(3) requires a call to svc_run().  Both of these block.  From what I remember of zeromq it requires a call to a blocking function too (and it creates loads of threads!)  All of these require me to abandon the select driven architecture in my daemon which has worked well up till now.  FastRPC seems to be local only - which rules that out.  Google protocol buffers might work although I would prefer something text based and self describing.

Comment: @alex In that case I think I'd build my own mechanism based on events with a dispatcher/parser. I'd probably start with something based on my emesary C++  class library

Comment: Thanks for the earlier pointer regarding google protocol buffers. I've now built something using those as marshallers but I needed to write my own code to handle input and output without blocking. It seemed wrong to not reuse existing code for this but everything I found required calls to blocking code which would break my event driven architecture.